# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Fiz um programa simples, apenas para calcular uma função matemática para eu obter um resultado exato, porém houve algumas complicações no Java.

> ```
> Digite o valor de x:
> 0.2
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2388)
>   at funçaofx.funx.main(funx.java:15)
> C:\Users\Renan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> Java returned: 1 FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 2 segundos)
> ```

Código:

```
package funçaofx;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class funx {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        float x;
        float y;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o valor de x:");
        x = input.nextFloat();
        input.nextLine();
        y = (x - ((x*(x - 1))/(2*x)));
        System.out.println("valor calculado por F(x):"+y);
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Tentei meter um `double` ao invés do `float` (pois preciso fazer um cálculo bem
preciso), porém o programa dá o mesmo problema, alguém tem alguma idéia de como
se resolve isso?

Nota: Se eu coloco inteiros como *1* ou *0*, o programa executa normalmente, porém ao colocar um numero mais preciso como *0.2* ou *0.0038* por exemplo, aparece essa `exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu valor for `2.5` insira como entrada `2,5` usando a vírgula `,`.

Comment: estou usando netbeans e estou usando com ponto

Comment: @ReZ tente com virgula, aqui funcionou.

Comment: @ReZ tem que ser com virgula mesmo!

Comment: @ReZ eu falei, mas corrigi logo depois que fiz o teste. Usando a virgula, deve corrigir seu problema.

Comment: ow vlws kara,é mesmo,coloquei com virgula no netbeans e a parada nao deu problema

Comment: @ReZ precisar, só vir aqui e dar um grito. Abraços. Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a documentação:

> A exceção [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) é lançada pela instância do
>   `Scanner` quando o  *token* recuperado não corresponde ao tipo
>   esperado. `InputMismatchException` se estende da classe
>   [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html), que é usada para indicar que o elemento
>   solicitado não existe.

Isso acontece porque o [separador decimal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal) do teu sistema é representado por uma vírgula e não um ponto. Trocá-lo pela *vírgula* resolve o teu problema de forma parcial, se você executar o teu código em um sistema onde o separador decimal é um *ponto*, o problema volta a ocorrer.

<sub>**Nota**: Você pode alterar essa configuração no Painel de Controle → Relógio, Idioma e Região → Alterar formatos de data, hora ou número →  Configurações adicionais.</sub>

---

Você pode preferir colocar o código num bloco `Try/Catch` e informar o usuário que o valor digitado está incorreto.

```
float x, y;

try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Digite o valor de x: ");

    try {
         x = input.nextFloat();

         y = (x - ((x* (x - 1)) / (2* x)));
         System.out.println("valor calculado por F(x): " + y);

    } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
         System.out.println("Erro! O valor digitado não é válido. Tente novamente!");
         // err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/V0tBKy)</kbd>

Uma outra alternativa é tratar a exceção lançada usando o [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) para formatar o valor num padrão onde o *ponto* seja reconhecido como separador decimal.

```
float x, y;

NumberFormat nformat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Digite o valor de x: ");

try {
     x = input.nextFloat();
} catch (InputMismatchException err) {
     x = nformat.parse(input.nextLine()).floatValue();
     // err.printStackTrace();
}

y = (x - ((x* (x - 1)) / (2* x)));

System.out.println("valor calculado por F(x): " + y);
input.close();
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/AunxR6)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

O erro está aqui:

```
x = input.nextFloat();
```

Quando você digita , por exemplo,  o valor 0.2 e a variável x recebe esse valor, ocorre a exceção pois alguns lugares convencionam o ponto (.), enquanto outros lugares utilizam a vírgula (,) para este fim.

O que determina isso é o padrão do idioma da máquina que o código está sendo escrito.

Por exemplo:

- Se o idioma estiver em inglês o padrão é o ponto (.);
- Se o idioma estiver em português o padrão é a vírgula (,).

**1° Solução:**

- Utilizar a vírgula ao invés do ponto, visto que o seu sistema convenciona o uso dela (,).

**2° Solução**

- Caso você queira realmente utilizar o ponto aos invés da vírgula, a classe Scanner tem um método chamado useLocale onde é possível especificar a localidade do padrão desejado.

No seu caso:

```
input.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Como ficaria o código:

```
    float x;
    float y;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    input.useLocale(Locale.US);
    System.out.println("Digite o valor de x:");
    x = input.nextFloat(); //Esse método especifica a regra que queremos utilizar.
    input.nextLine();
    y = (x - ((x*(x - 1))/(2*x)));
    System.out.println("valor calculado por F(x):"+y);
    input.close();
```

Dessa forma, você conseguirá utilizar a entrada utilizando ponto (.).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]